# return value from nested function in javascript for e2e testing

Tags: javascript

Consider this code:

file1.js:

```
var out=uidata.getUiData1();
    console.log('book',out);
```

file2.js:

```
this.getUiData1=function(){
            xmlcontroller.getXmlLoader('book1',function(returnData){
            var book1=returnData;

            return book1;

        });

};
```

During execution of this code 'out'  var get undefined value.please guide me to the output.

Comment: Looks like `getXmlLoader` runs some asynchronous code so that means that `book1` will be available only when that code is complete and you can't get its value before that. Either change that code to be synchronous or change your logic to pass a callback function to `getUiData1` where you will have the `console.log()` line.

Comment: Declare out variable as global variable, without var, and change the value of out inside response of getXmlLoader. Remember you cannot access the out variable till xml returned his reponse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just return the `book1` to the function `getXmlLoader()`, but you have to return it to `getUiData1()`

```
this.getUiData1=function(){
      //you have to return the parameter
      var book1;
      xmlcontroller.getXmlLoader('book1',function(returnData){
            book1=returnData;            
      });
      return book1;

};
```